# The code does not work when I update a variable

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to display two images of cards in a simple GUI(can only be accessed online at http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_8Poew9PXI8_1.py)

```
import simplegui

#images to be displayed
ace_hearts = simplegui.load_image("http://i.imgur.com/Nbr6Dzi.png")
two_spades = simplegui.load_image("http://i.imgur.com/OWayJ1T.png")

# global constants
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 100


# mouseclick handler
def click(pos):
    return pos


# draw handler
def draw(canvas):
    IMG_WIDTH = 67
    IMG_HEIGHT = 100
    img_center = [IMG_WIDTH // 2, IMG_HEIGHT // 2]
    canvas.draw_image(two_spades, (img_center), 
        (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), (img_center), (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    img_center[0] += IMG_WIDTH
    canvas.draw_image(ace_hearts, (img_center), 
        (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), (img_center), (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))

# create frame and register draw handler    
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Test image", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
frame.set_canvas_background("Gray")
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(click)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# start frame
frame.start()
```

The problem is, that when I update the value of img_center[0], the code won't display the second image "**ace-hearts**".

Then I remove the line

```
img_center[0] += IMG_WIDTH
```

The second image is correctly displayed "on top" of "**two-spades**".

Does anyone know why updating this variable won't produce the correct results (**ace-hearts** should be displayed to the right of **two-hearts**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second and fourth parameter given to [`draw_image`](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#draw_image) are `center_source` and `center_dest`. When you draw the second image you need to keep `center_source` the same and only modify `center_dest`:

```
def draw(canvas):
    IMG_WIDTH = 67
    IMG_HEIGHT = 100
    source_center = [IMG_WIDTH // 2, IMG_HEIGHT // 2]
    dest_center = [IMG_WIDTH // 2, IMG_HEIGHT // 2]
    canvas.draw_image(two_spades, (source_center), 
        (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), (dest_center), (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    dest_center[0] += IMG_WIDTH
    canvas.draw_image(ace_hearts, (source_center), 
        (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), (dest_center), (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
```

Working example: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_5Cm7ZlARnQ_0.py